# How communicate with springboot and ionic?

Tags: spring-boot, ionic4

i am using ionic 4 with spring boot web service , the problem is after installation application in my phone the web service is not run ?

i use in Controller.java

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
public class CarController {
    @Autowired
    CarRepository carRepository;
    
    @GetMapping(path = "/cars")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Car>> retriveCars() {
        try {
            List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
            carRepository.findAll().forEach(cars::add);
            
            
            if (cars.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(cars, HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    
    @PostMapping(path = "/car")
    public ResponseEntity<Car> saveCar (@RequestBody Car car) {
        try {
            Car _car= carRepository.save(new Car(UUID.randomUUID(), car.getMake(), car.getModel()));
            return new ResponseEntity<>(_car, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
            
        }
    }
```

and in api.service.ts

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Car } from './car';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  baseUrl='http://localhost:8081';

  retrieveCars(){
    return this.http.get<Car[]>(this.baseUrl+ '/cars');
  }

  saveCar(car: Car) {
    return this.http.post<Car>(this.baseUrl+'/car', car);
  }
```

My question is how can i communicate in ionic and springboot?
**i need help please**

Answer (score 0):

yes it will not work because http gives mixed data in mobiles and emulators....  it will work perfectly with browsers but not with emulators and devices

Solution is simple just use **https** to get data in api.service.ts in baseUrl everything else is fine

> **https**://localhost:8081

> baseUrl='http://localhost:8081';

Comment: I did this to no avail 

Comment: sorry I didnt get you kindly explain. and kindly check in your browser first that if data is coming or not and I believe you are new to stackoverflow community next time you post comments or answers be specific and explain the problem